# App.config not working whit https

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller, app-config

We'll go over from http to https and the introduction of certificates and it has given us some problems. When I change the values in the `<binding>`. It has no effect on the size of the data I get back. What is it I have forgotten my `App.config`? Or lies the fault elsewhere?

```
       <binding>
         <binaryMessageEncoding />
         <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         maxBufferSize="2147483647"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"/>
       </binding>
```

Comment: Can you get into more detail please? 1. What are you trying to do. 2. What is working with http, which isn't with https? 3. What's the connection with model-view-controller ?

Comment: We'll changes from lokal server to Microsoft NAV and for that we need https. Previously, we could in the config file to determine how much traffic should be allowed.
Now, nothing happens when we change the values of httpTransport. The connection whit the server is working, but it gives us arbitrary amount of data back.